# Update object in relations in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner in Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 5.8.

I have this code :

```
class Client extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes, Deactivation, Notifiable;



    protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'email_verified_at',
        'password_assigned_at',
        'verify_token',
        'password',
        'type'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'verify_token',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'password_assigned_at',
        'email_verified_at',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deactivated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];

public function invoiceAddress()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Addresses', 'client_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

and Adress:

```
class Addresses extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'company_name',
        'nip',
        'address',
        'city',
        'postal_code'
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'deleted_at'
    ];

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }

}
```

In controller I have:

```
$bla = Client::with('invoiceAddress')->where('id', 1)->get();
```

I want update object in relation invoiceAddress.
I make code to normal update. I try this code:

```
$data = [
                'client_id' => $id,
                'company_name' => $request->input('company_invoice_company_name'),
                'nip' => $request->input('company_invoice_nip'),
                'address' => $request->input('company_invoice_address'),
                'city' => $request->input('company_invoice_city]'),
                'postal_code' => $request->input('company_invoice_postal_code'),
            ];

$client->invoiceAddress()->update($data);
```

but this is not working. How can I make it?

I need update object in relation. My code not working

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

In your **$fillable** of `Addresses` is saying `user_id` and in relationship you've used `client_id`

change `client_id` to `user_id`

```
 public function invoiceAddress()
 {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Addresses', 'user_id', 'id');
 }
```

One more issue I can see is you're using `get()` method it should be `first();`

```
$bla = Client::with('invoiceAddress')->where('id', 1)->first();
$bla->invoiceAddress()->update($data);
```